# Riemann sphere in hypercomplex number sets?

Tags: riemann-surfaces

Do Riemann spheres work on bigger number sets than complex numbers? I think it would be interesting to think of quaternions as a 5D sphere or something, but I really don't know if the maths of Riemann spheres work in other dimensions. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. These correspondences are actually really important when trying to understand the topology of spheres because of the existence of the corresponding [Hopf maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_fibration#Generalizations). Just like how $S^2$ is homeomorphic to the complex projective line $\mathbf{CP}^1$, we have the correspondences
$$\begin{align}S^1&\cong\mathbf{RP}^1\\
S^2&\cong\mathbf{CP}^1\\
S^4&\cong\mathbf{HP}^1\\
S^8&\cong\mathbf{OP}^1
\end{align}$$
for the real, complex, quaternionic, and octonionic number systems, respectively.